# No RC messages at the start between kernel loading and login prompt

Tags: boot, gentoo, tty, rc, openrc

I have a 4.3.2 kernel and OpenRC 0.19.1. After the kernel loads there is no messages from the RC scripts. And then, there is the prompt to log in.

There is another system with identical `rc.conf` and it boots with RC messages in place, so I presume this isn’t an openrc issue, and rather, an issue with console – I’ve read that the same thing may happen if the kernel has a serial console set as primary. But there is no `CONFIG_*` parameter having ‘serial’ that is set:

```
# zgrep -i '^config.*serial' /proc/config.gz
#
```

`CONFIG_*` parameters that have ‘console’ differ only by `CONFIG_VT_CONSOLE_SLEEP=y` that is present only on the machine that doesn’t show RC messages.

There is no `console=` parameter passed via kernel command line:

```
# cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.3.2 root=LABEL=p_root rootflags=data=journal,errors=remount-ro,barrier=1 elevator=bfq acpi_osi=Linux
```

And there’s no other tty than tty0 in dmesg.

```
# dmesg | grep -i tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
#
```

Here’s my rc.conf:

```
# grep ^[^#] /etc/rc.conf
rc_parallel="YES"
rc_interactive="NO"
rc_shell=/sbin/sulogin
rc_depend_strict="NO"
rc_hotplug="*" # !net.*
rc_logger="YES"
rc_log_path="/var/log/rc.log"
unicode="YES"
rc_tty_number=12
```

Another thing probably worth mentioning is that there’s no output on tty12, where the copy of the messages should go. Neither at the RC boot time, not after it. But /var/log/rc.log does exist and has all the messages.

/etc/inittab files are also identical on both machines. I don’t remember ever editing that file, but here’s its contents, just in case:

```
# grep ^[^#] /etc/inittab
id:3:initdefault:
si::sysinit:/sbin/rc sysinit
rc::bootwait:/sbin/rc boot
l0:0:wait:/sbin/rc shutdown 
l0s:0:wait:/sbin/halt -dhp
l1:1:wait:/sbin/rc single
l2:2:wait:/sbin/rc nonetwork
l3:3:wait:/sbin/rc default
l4:4:wait:/sbin/rc default
l5:5:wait:/sbin/rc default
l6:6:wait:/sbin/rc reboot
l6r:6:wait:/sbin/reboot -dk
su0:S:wait:/sbin/rc single
su1:S:wait:/sbin/sulogin
c1:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty1 linux
c2:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty2 linux
c3:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty3 linux
c4:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty4 linux
c5:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty5 linux
c6:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty6 linux
ca:12345:ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -r now
x:a:once:/etc/X11/startDM.sh
```

---

Update:

To @MarkWagner.

```
# tty
/dev/tty1
# /etc/init.d/hostname status
 * status: started
```

Comment: Is there any output when you manually run an init script, e.g., `/etc/init.d/hostname status`?

Comment: Does the machine n question have Splash/Framebuffer/Graphical TTY etc enabled in the kernel?  If so, you won't see any RC messages unless you physically press a key on the affected machine during boot, as the RAM disk etc is switching resolutions and counting penguins based on the number of cores you have.

Comment: @MarkWagner yes, I’ve updated my post with the output.

Comment: @eyoung100 I think no, I didn’t enable decorations or set up some graphical splashes. Here’s FB related options from the kernel that are enabled, maybe you would find something suspicious or lacking? http://pastie.org/pastes/10746464/text

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi yes, I have, it starts in the boot runlevel, though, I suppose it gets up after the initrams stage, for its sole purpose is to find the appropriate partition to `switch_root` to. What does a syslog daemon has to do with RC output anyway?

Comment: @tijagi Nothing. I just confused with an old problem (when distribution started to log early console messages), but the effect should be inverted. Sorry